# Energy estimate for non classic heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let
$$u_t = au_{xx}+ cu_x, a>0$$
With
$$u(x,0)=f(x), u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$$

Find a bound for $c$ so that the solution doesn't grow for each $f(x)$.

My attempt (all integrals are from $0$ to $\pi$):

$$uu_t = auu_{xx}+ cuu_x$$

$$0.5||u||^2_t = \int uu_t dx= a\int uu_{xx}dx+ c\int uu_x dx= auu_x|_0^\pi - a\int (u_x)^2dx + \frac{c}{2} \int(u^2)_xdx $$

$$=0 - a\int (u_x)^2dx + \frac{c}{2} u^2|_0^\pi = - a\int (u_x)^2dx + \frac{c}{2}(u^2(\pi ,t) - u^2(0,t))=-a \int (u_x)^2dx<0$$

Does that mean that the solution dos not grow for every $c$? It seems that I'm missing something.

Comment: $\ldots \leq 0$. Other than that, I believe your argument is sound. The mechanism provided by the $c u_x$ term is referred to as advection: it merely transport the quantity $u$ but does not add to it. Since you have $u = 0$ on both sides, whatever is transported to the boundary is annihilated there.

Comment: @user66081. Thanks a lot! If you could answer another question that would be great: what would happen if instead $u(0,t) = 0$ I'll write $u_x(0,t) = 0$?Then the last term would be $- a\int (u_x)^2dx + \frac{c}{2}(0 - u^2(0,t))$. Does that mean that $c\geq 0$? Can  I do any better?

Comment: $c \geq 0$ would suffice. But the sharp condition is of course $c \geq -2 a \int |u_x|^2 dx / |u(x = 0)|^2$. The quantity on the right is bdd above by a negative constant; I believe, you find the constant by setting $u := \cos(x / 2)$.